# Camera preview squashed but only while recording

Tags: android, camera

I'm a bit confused by this one.. On one of the phones (Samsung Galaxy Ace Style), when `MediaRecorder` starts, the camera preview gets squashed. However the preview is fine before the record button is pressed and the resolution is fine in the actual video file.

Why does the preview resolution change when `MediaRecorder` starts, and more importantly, which resolution does it change to? Is that the video size that is used for preview during recording? Although that doesn't make much sence.. Anyway, these are the values I get from the camera:

```
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] Requested preview size 800 x 480
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] Requested video size 1280 x 720
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] Requested picture size 2560 x 1920
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] requested jpeg thumbnail size 512 x 384
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] set optimal jpeg thumbnail size 512 x 384
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] m_bNoDisplayMode = 0
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] dualrecording-hint : 0 m_FaceAE=1 Camera ID=0
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] ZSL = off
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] prev_val = off
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] str_val = off
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] flash mode = off
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] AEC lock = false
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] AWB lock = false
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] mHdrMode 0 mTakeLowlight 0
02-22 19:20:55.857: W/QCameraParameters(230): [PARM_DBG] live snapshot size 1280 x 720
```

EDIT:

I calculate the preview size based on the available preview sizes from the camera and the size of the surface view. I calculate the video size based on the video sizes returned from the camera `getSupportedVideoSizes`, selecting 16:9 first, and if that fails - defaulting to the largest. If the list returned by `getSupportedVideoSizes` is null, I fallback to `getSupportedPreviewSizes`. However, this fallback will go through video size logic and not the preview size logic. Looking at the docs

> If the returned list is not null, the returned list will contain at
>   least one Size and one of the sizes in the returned list must be
>   passed to MediaRecorder.setVideoSize() for camcorder application if
>   camera is used as the video source. In this case, the size of the
>   preview can be different from the resolution of the recorded video
>   during video recording.

So maybe this phone returns null for `getSupportedPreviewSizes`, my fallback gives me a different resolution to the one I use for preview (as the list is passed through different logic), therefore I'm setting a video size different to the preview size on a phone that doesn't support it, hence the squashed preview during recording. Although this is all theory for now..

Comment: Do you get the supported video sizes and select optimal video size, then apply it to your media recorder while initalizing media recorder?

Comment: Yes, that's the video size shown in the logs. I'll update the question with some more details on how I make these calculations